# Python 3 Website detects scraper when using User-Agent spoofing

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib, user-agent

I'm trying to scrape some information from Indeed.com using urllib.  Occasionally, the job link gets redirected to the hiring company's webpage.  When this happens, Indeed throws up some html about using an incompatible browser or device, rather than continuing to the redirected page.  After looking around, I found that in most cases spoofing urllib's user agent to look like a browser is enough to get around this, but this doesn't seem to be the case here.

Any suggestions on where to go beyond spoofing the User-Agent?  Is it possible Indeed is able to realize the User-Agent is spoofed, and that there is no way around this?

Here's an example of the code:

```
import urllib
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar

ua = UserAgent()

website = 'http://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=0fd52fac51427150&fccid=7f79c79993ec7e60'
req = urllib.request.Request(website)
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', ua.chrome)]
response = opener.open(req)

print(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could try using Selenium in a headless approach (using Xvfb), which would "avoid" the detection of a browser by actually using the browser (but in a programmatic way).

Answer (score 2):

This header usually works :

```
HDR = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'}
```

Another option is to use the [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/) package.